# How to prove that a grammar is unambiguous?

Tags: context-free-grammar

`E → I | C | (E+E) | (E∗E)
I → y | z
C → 4`

It is written that it is unambiguous and also I understand intuitively that given grammar is unambiguous. But for now, all I can do is to argue. Can anyone tell me how to prove that a grammar is unambiguous?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Has been asked before:
https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2320/how-to-prove-that-a-grammar-is-unambiguous

Please use Google the next time before asking.